# csv parsing and adding floats is returning a casting error

Tags: python

I am parsing through a csv file and pulling strings that can be turned into floats. When converting them I'm getting the right data type but I keep getting this error on my addition line. I have no idea as to why

```
    total = 0.0;
    for line in csv_reader:
      if(line[0] == 'Jill'):
        total += float(line[3]);
    print(total);
```

i am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edwinregalado/Desktop/FarmersFridge/parseCSV.py", line 22, in <module>
    total += float(line[3]);
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what is in `line`? It is hard to troubleshoot without the data.

Comment: At least one row in the csv contains something in the fourth column that can't be converted to a float.

Comment: Is `line[3]` a number-like string? My guess is that it is not.

Comment: Unlike `int()`, `float()` doesn't like empty strings, so `float("")` will raise that exact error. You may have to explicitly check for them and substitute `"0"`.

Comment: You can handle empty strings with `total += float(line[3]) if line[3] is not "" else 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely that you are trying to read a string that doesn't convert nicely into a float (2.2.0 for example). Try printing line[3] before executing the casting and addition. The last print output before an error should tell you what is not being cast correctly and often times, it's pretty obvious why casting of this value fails.